# How to Insert/update/delete product in Google shopping using google-api-php-client

Tags: google-api-php-client

I have download files from Github https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client. I have gone through the files but not found any code to Insert/update/delete product in Google shopping using php code. Can anyone tell how to to Insert/update/delete product in Google shopping using Google API php version 2. Please help.

Comment: how did you go about setting up the project to run? from authorization to getting the list of products?

Answer (score 0):

The client example code can be found [on github](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-shopping-samples/tree/master/php) the ProductsSample.php will probably be of particular interest.

Comment: how did you go about setting up the project to run? from authorization to getting the list of products?